# Generating Function of a series expressed as a product and proving the function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-explanation, generating-functions

> Question: $h_n$ is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to
>
> $$e_1*1^2 + e_2*2^2 + e_3*3^2 + \cdots + e_n*n^2 = n$$
>
> where $n\ge0$. What would be the ordinary (not exponential) generating function $G(x)$ expressed as a product for the sequence $\{h_n\}$ from $n=0$ to $n=\infty$? After that, prove your $G(x)$ answer is correct.

When I did this, I was able to express my $G(x)$ as a sum, but I was not able to express it in the required form. Also, I believe the way to prove this would be either using induction or some combinatorics proving method, but I am not sure how I would apply that.

Could someone help out please?
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you obtained for $G(x)$ as a sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general framework for using generating functions to count the number of solutions to integer equations is this. If you want to count the number of solutions to 
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots=n,
$$
satisfying the constraints
$$
x_1\in S_1,x_2\in S_2,x_3\in S_3,\dots
$$
then the generating function is
$$
\left(\sum_{i\in S_1} x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i\in S_2} x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i\in S_3} x^i\right)\cdots
$$
Now, in your case, you do not have just a sum of variables, you have a variables times certain coefficiets:
$$
1x_1+4x_2+9x_3+\dots=n
$$
(Notice I have let the sum extend infinitely, which does not affect the number of solutions, but does let us apply this method). However, if you instead replace each summand $k^2x_k$ with a new variable $y_k$, then the equation is 
$$
y_1+y_2+y_3+\dots=n,
$$
which fits in our framework. However, whereas the $x_k$ could be any nonnegative integer, the fact that $y_k=k^2x_k$ means the $y_k$ must obey certain restraints. What are they?

Comment: I am not sure what they are, but I hope the following kinda helps answer that question:

Since y1 is divisible by 1, y2 is divisible by 4, y3 is divisible by 9, ... so on, I put G(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+...)*(1+x^4+x^8+...)*(1+x^9+x^18+...)*... = (1/(1-x))*(1/(1-x^4))*(1/(1-x^9))*... But would this be considered as G(x) being expressed in product form or is there a specific method of expressing sums in product form? 

Also, I don't know how I would prove that this G(x) is correct using either induction or some combinatorics proving method.  Thanks

Comment: @Alex You computed correctly. And your comment has "expressed $G(x)$ as a product," because it is the product of functions of the form $(1-x^{n^2})^{-1}$. As for the proof part, I am not sure what is expected of you. The usual proof of correctness of the g.f. is to say "it is obvious based on how multiplication of power series works." You could view the first three lines of my answer as a lemma I used, and it would be a pain and not very illuminating to rigorously prove that lemma.

Comment: Thank you for everything!

Comment: @Alex Happy to talk about combinatorics!